# how to handle outdated suggested edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

If I proposed a suggested edit for a post, during waiting for reviewing, the post was updated by an user with high reputation, generated a **revision 2** then my suggested edit will be outdated status.

my questions are

1. Whether is the reviewer known my suggested edit is **outdated** status?
2. If more than 3 reviewers approved my suggested edit, original **revision 2** will stay here  or will be removed?

Comment: Do you have a specific example?  I don't see one in your profile.

Comment: no, I am just curious **stackoverflow** how to make decision for specific case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Normally* users are prevented from making additional edits if a suggested edit is pending. The *edit* link is replaced by *edit (1)* which when clicked brings up a popup-up showing the pending edit and the option to review the edit.

If a another user opened the edit view before you submitted your suggested edit, however, submitting the new edit will automatically *reject* the pending suggested edit (blamed on the Community User).

In the case where both you and another user have the edit view open, and your suggested edit is submitted *after* the other editor has submitted theirs, then your suggested edit will look as if you edited the other revision.

Reviewers cannot see this, and this can often lead to your edit being rejected. If it is accepted anyway, it'll be applied as a new revision, undoing whatever the other editor had done.

Comment: thank you very much. so 1. reviewer doesn't know whether the revision is outdated or not. 2. In review diff pane, left side is original version, right side is edited version. maybe the both are not latest, if the revision is approved, the history will look like that first rollback to left revision and then add right side edited revision. right?

Comment: @CloudBSD: left side is the revision *at the time you submit your suggestion* (which can be different from what you started your edit from), the right-side is your suggested revision.

Comment: @CloudBSD: When approved, the diff will remain the same.

Comment: if approved, the diff will same, why?

Comment: @CloudBSD: because when you submit your suggested edit, the diff is made between your version and the last revision of the post. So reviewers see that diff, and if approved, that is the change made between the last revision and yours.

Comment: that means approved suggested edit is changed, right? Left side is from original last version to real last version.

Comment: @CloudBSD: you are confusing diffs and revisions, I think. You submit a new revision, reviewers see the difference between your revision and the last one on the post. The *diff* may have changed, because the last revision is newer than what you started from.